# Как спроектировать класс

Tags: java, android, ооп

Есть `RecyclerView`, в который я помещаю инфу о компах. Это три поля - id, pcName, invnumber. При нажатии на элемент открывается новый `activity`, в котором уже идет детальное описание. Т.е. там будет отображаться все то же самое, плюс два поля filial и dopInfo. Я решил все данные вывести в абстрактный класс и расширить дочерние классы.

```
abstract public class PC {
    String id;
    int pcName;
    String invNumber;
    String filial;
    String dopInfo;
}

public class RecyclerPc extends PC {
   ...
}

public class InfoPc extends PC {
   ...
}
```

Но что-то мне кажется что я делаю не так. Подскажите, как лучше реализовать это все?

Comment: >Я решил все данные вывести в абстрактный класс

а зачем? Вам нужна иерархия классов? Сомневаюсь

Comment: У меня побольше полей будет. Это я так примерно показал. А почему мне не нужна иерархия)?

Comment: А почему она вам нужна? В чем ее необходимость?

Comment: Пока вы просто выводите атрибуты инветарных вещей, вам не нужно их наследовать. Просто у них разные атрибуты, но ничем принципиальным они не различаются, для программы это все еще DTO одинакового смысла.

Comment: наследование - это такая вещь, когда тебя ПОЧТИ устраивает поведение базового класса, и ты хочешь его изменить.

Comment: Если уж пишите код, то пишите его правильно. Всегда называйте вещи своими именами. Например: filial пишите branch. dopInfo пишите additionalInformation. И так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам уже писали - в данном случае наследование вам не надо.

А вот в каком случае оно вам пригодилось бы:
у вас есть 3 вида компов:

- ноутбук выданный на руки
- сервер
- рабочий комп

У них всех есть общие поля: `id, pcName, invnumber`, а вот для каждого из 3 приведенных выше категорий есть уникальные поля, например - для ноутбука - адрес человека который его забрал, для сервера - его ip адресс, а для рабочего - пароль для удаленного администрирования.

В данном случае имеет смысл сделать наследование с иерархией и показывать все 3 вида компов одним списком, а при клике на пункт списка открывать уникальную Activity для выбранного типа.

У вас такого нет, так что зачем усложнять?